# Cordova Media Plugin setVolume() not working

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

Here is my play function: As you can see I setVolume() in multiple locations to 0. This has absolutely no effect. I've tried to also set to 0.8, 0.2, doesn't matter it wont work. I've also tried non string value, which doesn't really matter as the value is converted to a float val inside of the Obj-C module. I also NSLogged to ensure the value was being passed correctly and it is.

Testing with iPad iOS 9.2 | Cordova 6.2 | Cordova Media Plugin 2.3.1.

```
play: function(src, seekTime)
        {
            App.Log.info('Playing audio source', src);
            seekTime = seekTime ? seekTime : 0;
            var obj = {
                source: src,
                startTime: new Date().getTime(),
                seekTime: seekTime,
                duration: 0,
                preloadedNext: false,
                audioSource: false
            };
            obj.audioSource = new Media(src, function(event){
                $this.player().onAudioEnd(event, obj);
            }, function(){
                //on error
            }, function(status)
            {
                obj.audioSource.setVolume("0.0");
                if(status == 2){
                    obj.audioSource.setVolume("0.0");
                    obj.audioSource.seekTo(obj.seekTime * 1000);
                    obj.timer = setInterval(function(){
                        obj.seekTime++;
                        obj.duration = obj.audioSource._duration;
                        if(obj.duration < 0){
                            return;
                        }
                        if(obj.seekTime >= (obj.duration - $this.default.fadeTime))
                        {
                            if(obj.preloadedNext){
                                return;
                            }
                            obj.preloadedNext = true;
                            $this.player().preloadNext(obj);
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }

            });
            obj.audioSource.setVolume("0.0");
            obj.audioSource.play();
            obj.audioSource.setVolume("0.0");
            obj.audioSource.seekTo(obj.seekTime * 1000);
            console.log('Audio Source', JSON.stringify(obj));
            $this.playing.push(obj);
}
```

Any help or direction would be awesome.

Comment: consider filling a bug report on issues.cordova.io

Comment: did you check the `Android` version? I don't have `mac` on me for the moment but did you check the execution are actuly enter the `if` at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/master/src/ios/CDVSound.m#L260 ?

Comment: @anthony.c i tried out the media plugin in a sample app and setvolume works perfectly fine. Have posted the test app in my github - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Media Please check out to see if it helps. Also i noticed the plugin version you mentioned is 2.3.1 But if i add the plugin using add command, the latest version available is 2.3.0 Hope you are testing in beta branch. Please check out the master branch and see if it helps. Keep me posted

Comment: You are using a local file as I'm using an external file I wonder if that makes any difference?

Comment: @anthony.c Tried playing remote file using following code: function playRemoteFile() {
 var media = new Media("http://localhost:8080/test.mp3");
 media.setVolume(0.1);
    media.play();
} It works fine in iOS device running with version 9.2. Did you tried with Media plugin version 2.3.0 as i mentioned earlier?

Comment: I'm curious what you are doing in the preloadNext method specifically at this line.  "$this.player().preloadNext(obj)"  Can you please post that method?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sample code works fine and it is tested in Android & iOS devices:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="playMp3">Play MP3</button><br><br>
        <button id="playMp3Mild">Play MP3 Mild</button><br><br>
        <button id="playRemoteFile">Play Remote File</button>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js:**

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.querySelector("#playMp3").addEventListener("touchend", playMP3, false);
    document.querySelector("#playMp3Mild").addEventListener("touchend", playMp3Mild, false);
    document.querySelector("#playRemoteFile").addEventListener("touchend", playRemoteFile, false);

};

function playMP3() {
    var mp3URL = getMediaURL("sounds/button-1.mp3");
    var media = new Media(mp3URL, null, mediaError);
    media.setVolume(1.0);
    media.play();
}

function playMp3Mild() {
    var mp3URL = getMediaURL("sounds/button-1.mp3");
    var media = new Media(mp3URL, null, mediaError);
    media.setVolume(0.1);
    media.play();
}

function playRemoteFile() {
    var media = new Media("http://SERVER_IP:PORT/media/test.mp3");
    media.setVolume(0.1);
    media.play();
}

function getMediaURL(s) {
    if(device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") return "/android_asset/www/" + s;
    return s;
}

function mediaError(e) {
    alert('Media Error');
    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

The sample app can be downloaded from the [github page](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Media). Ensure to add media and device plugin to test the same. More info can be found on the README file of the sample app. Hope it helps.

Comment: @DavidNathan Hi David, I dont understand how this issue is related to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will solve your issue, but maybe the volume is not set to zero because the setVolume is called too "early". Could you please try this code and report eventually some logs in order to refine my solution?

```
play: function(src, seekTime)
        {
            App.Log.info('Playing audio source', src);
            seekTime = seekTime ? seekTime : 0;
            var obj = {
                source: src,
                startTime: new Date().getTime(),
                seekTime: seekTime,
                duration: 0,
                preloadedNext: false,
                audioSource: false
            };
            obj.audioSource = new Media(src, function(event){
                $this.player().onAudioEnd(event, obj);
            }, function(){
                //on error
            }, function(status)
            {
                obj.audioSource.setVolume("0.0");
                if(status == 2){
                    obj.audioSource.setVolume("0.0");
                    obj.audioSource.seekTo(obj.seekTime * 1000);
                    obj.timer = setInterval(function(){
                        obj.seekTime++;
                        obj.duration = obj.audioSource._duration;
                        if(obj.duration < 0){
                            return;
                        }
                        if(obj.seekTime >= (obj.duration - $this.default.fadeTime))
                        {
                            if(obj.preloadedNext){
                                return;
                            }
                            obj.preloadedNext = true;
                            $this.player().preloadNext(obj);
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }

            });
            //obj.audioSource.setVolume("0.0");
            obj.audioSource.play();
            setTimeout(function() { //try to set volume to 0 after 10 milliseconds
               obj.audioSource.setVolume("0.0");
            }, 10);
            setTimeout(function() { //try to seekTo after 1 second
                obj.audioSource.seekTo(obj.seekTime * 1000);
            }, 1000);
            console.log('Audio Source', JSON.stringify(obj));
            $this.playing.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking you time to reply, if you notice above in the if(status == 2){} block... If status = 2 it means the audio file is in the "Running State" so setting volume at that point should allow me to have volume control even if it isn't ready quite yet outside of that block.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set a mute delay of one second to see if it creates at least a correct delayed behaviour? (process of elimination)

```
setTimeout(function() {
obj.audioSource.setVolume("0.0");
}, 1000);
```